# XML find each javascript request , another each in the main each

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

i've been working on android application with the help of phonegap framework .I've made 1 php -xml file to parse the data from my site to application. The problem i have is that when i click button , i want to get all the `<vic></vic>` separated of the clicked cat_id
Heres the link with xml file
http://smeshnoto.eu/rss/mobile_vicove_cats.php

At the moment i have this code:

```
function showVicoveKategorii(){
      var xml = '';
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://smeshnoto.eu/rss/mobile_vicove_cats.php",
      dataType: 'xml',
     success: kategorii,
     error: function () {
         alert('Грешка в сървъра');
     }
    });

}

function kategorii(xml){
     var obj = document.getElementById("vicove_kategorii_id");  
$(xml).find('category').each(function(){
  var catname = $(this).find('cat_name').text();
  var catid = $(this).find('cat_id').text();
  var titlevic = $(this).find('title_vic').text();
  var descvic = $(this).find('desc_vic').text();
  addContent(obj, '<a href="" onClick="alert(\''+descvic+'\');" data-role="button">'+catname+'</a>');

});

}
```

I want when i click the button the alert to be all `<vic></vic>` with `<br>` for example after every element , of course those `<vic></vic>` to be from the clicked category (cat_id)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use http://smeshnoto.eu/rss/mobile_vicove_cats.php?cat_id=ChosenID 
so you can get the items from the chosen id :)